# Capture Audio Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, icenium

I'm using  [Cordova Capture Audio](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio) on mobile device (iOS).

When I'm clicking on "Capture audio" button , nothing happen and the microphone appears only after I lock and unlock my phone . How can I fix this problem ?

Iphone 4 / iOS 6.1.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Icenium capture sample](https://github.com/Icenium/sample-capture) application works fine, so clone it and deploy it on your device to see whether it works for you as well. In this case you can compare the differences with your app or use it as a base for your app. If further help is needed, give more information e.g.: mobile device and OS version you're testing on.

Comment: I'll try it but it's very strange it works when I load my project for the first time and after I have to lock/unlock to get it work .

Comment: I'm using the code right here http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio

Comment: I try the Icenium sample application but I also have to lock/unlock to get i works ! Strange...

Comment: doesn't happen on my iphone, try restoring defaults on your device or try another device.